# PHP-SQL-Parser Why this lib parsed 'SIGNED' as a colref instead of reserved word?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parsing

Thanks for your help. So the question I'm asking is - Why https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser parsed 'SIGNED' as a colref? -. Is that a bug or there is a reason for that?

I'm parsing an expression like "WHERE ( CAST(table1.BIGINTField AS SIGNED) - CAST(table2.BIGINTField AS SIGNED) ) <= 11". The reason for the cast is that mysql fires a warning when trying to do so without the cast. I was reading the docs and I found this way to fix that, casting the bigint fields to signed. I'm using the version 4.1.1 of PHP-SQL-PARSER, I got problems with the last version.

This is the result I have got so far:

```
["WHERE"]=> array(3) { 
[0]=> array(4) { 
    ["expr_type"]=> string(8) "function" 
    ["base_expr"]=> string(4) "CAST" 
    ["sub_tree"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["expr_type"]=> string(10) "expression"
            ["base_expr"]=> string(51) "`table1`.`bigintfield` AS SIGNED"
            ["sub_tree"]=> array(3) { 
                [0]=> array(5) {
                    ["expr_type"]=> string(6) "colref"
                    ["base_expr"]=> string(41) "`table1`.`bigintfield`"
                    ["no_quotes"]=> array(2) {
                        ["delim"]=> string(1) "."
                        ["parts"]=> array(2) {
                            [0]=> string(26) "table1"
                            [1]=> string(10) "bigintfield"
                        }
                    } 
                    ["sub_tree"]=> bool(false)
                    ["position"]=> int(11)
                }
                [1]=> array(4) {
                    ["expr_type"]=> string(8) "reserved"
                    ["base_expr"]=> string(2) "AS"
                    ["sub_tree"]=> bool(false)
                    ["position"]=> int(53)
                } 
                [2]=> array(5) {
                    ["expr_type"]=> string(6) "colref"
                    ["base_expr"]=> string(6) "SIGNED"
                    ["no_quotes"]=> array(2) {
                        ["delim"]=> bool(false)
                        ["parts"]=> array(1) {
                            [0]=> string(6) "SIGNED"
                        }
                    }
                    ["sub_tree"]=> bool(false)
                    ["position"]=> int(56)
                }
            }
            ["alias"]=> bool(false)
            ["position"]=> int(11)
        }
    }
    ["position"]=> int(6)
} ...
```

Signed is a reserved word, I don't know why the sql parser say that it isn't.

[image]

Even though, Is there any different way to fix the problem facing arithmetical operations with bigints? I hope I'm not saying any foolishness haha.

Update: I almost forgot, I "fixed" it adding an if statement, performing the operation just when the value of the table1 is bigger than the value of the table2 but still.

Thanks for your help!
Sebastian C.

Comment: you should do better asking project authors.

Comment: Good idea. https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser/issues/263